# How do I get Powerline to produce the proper prompt arrows in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, prompt

There are several questions on this web site that are very similar to mine; however, the answers to those questions do not seem to solve my problem.  To start out with let me describe my process thus far.  I am running this process from Bash 3.2.57 on a Macintosh computer using OS X 11.0.1 (macOS Big Sur).

1. I cloned the Powerline fonts from with the following command.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git
   ```
2. This creates a directory titled `powerline_fonts` in my home directory
3. I `cd` into the `powerline_fonts` directory and run the command `./install.sh` to install the fonts
4. In install Powerline shell using `pip3 install powerline-shell` as directed at the website (Powerline Shell)[https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell]
5. I then update my `.profile` file with the following instructions

   ```
   function _update_ps1() {
            PS1=$(Powerline-shell $?)
   }

   if [[ STERM != linux && ! $PROMPT_COMMAND =~ _update_ps1 ]]; then
       PROMPT_COMMAND="_update_ps1; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
   fi
   ```
6. Next I create a `.config` directory in my home directory then create a `powerline-shell` directory in the `.config` directory.  Within the `powerline-shell` directory I created a `config.json` file and populated it with the following information

   ```
   {
     "segments": [
       "virtual_env",
       "ssh",
       "username",
       "cwd",
       "git",
       "git_stash",
       "jobs",
       "set_term_title",
       "svn",
       "newline",
       "root"
     ],
       "mode" : "flat",
       "cwd": {
       "mode": "plain",
       "max_depth": 4
       },
       "theme": "solarized_light"
   }
   ```
7. I then check my `locale` to make sure everything is configured correctly and I get the following output.

   $ locale
   LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_ALL=
8. I log out of my Bash session and log back in.  Powerline Shell has taken effect and I am getting a color coded prompt; however, instead of getting a nicely formatted arrow head at the end of each prompt I am only getting box like prompts like the ones shown here.  [image: current powerline shell prompts in Bash]

I suspect my problem is somewhere between steps 1 and 3, but none of the instructions I can find tell you to do anything different.

Comment: Did you change your terminal font to `PowerlineSymbols`?

Comment: No, I did not, how do I do that?

Comment: There should be a Preferences setting, but I don't have any idea where it is on a Mac terminal. The vim settings worked as advertised.